# MySQL Subquery slows down "main" query

Tags: mysql

Google and other posts didn't help me much, or I can't just read.

Got this query which gives me latest log entry for each ID

```
select companies.id, companies.name, companies.email, tal1.content, tal1.created_at
from log_items tal1
inner join companies on companies.id = loggable_id
where tal1.loggable_id IN 
                        (
                            select companies.id
                            from companies
                            where companies.disabled = "3"
                        ) 
and tal1.created_at = (select max(tal2.created_at) from log_items tal2 where tal2.loggable_id = tal1.loggable_id);
```

The problem is that subquery slows down the query to point where one could use meme "[ain't nobody got time for that](http://ci.memecdn.com/467/5509467.jpg)".

Subquery alone runs in under 1 second. And the "bigger" query runs also under one second when the ID is given straight, like:

```
select companies.id, companies.name, companies.email, tal1.content, tal1.created_at
            from log_items tal1
            inner join companies on companies.id = loggable_id
            where tal1.loggable_id IN 
(
"43c24b1d-cd48-4d3b-a75e-2de77a494ab9",
"c43b8c14-4593-4c3c-a383-e609003a09c8",
"5d559355-a4e0-4fea-9f50-fea1bbd8d011",
"f0ce61a2-d8d2-4651-ba12-a79f5515f527"
) 
and tal1.created_at = (select max(tal2.created_at) from log_items tal2 where tal2.loggable_id = tal1.loggable_id);
```

So what I'am doing wrong, or is there better way to do that subquery? Not that familiar with the SQL.

Comment: Instead of `IN` use `EXISTS`, it's a little bit faster!

Comment: if the "complex" sql is too slow, how about change the "complex" sql into two "simple" sql, and do it in one transaction?

Comment: Use an uncorellated subquery instead

Comment: IN vs. EXISTS no help

@GreenBlade I have tried that but can't get it working. Like could I give that subquery as variable or something? That query returns multiple values so I guess it won't work.

Comment: @Strawberry by uncorrelated you mean removing that tal1. from where clause?

Comment: In application, do the subquery first to get the IDs, and use the IDs as variables for the "bigger" query; Like this: 1. manually start a transaction; 2. do the subquery to get the IDs; 3. do the "bigger" query with the IDs in step 2; 4.end the transaction; The mysql-connector-lib should provide some API to support the multiple variable for a query;

Comment: I mean as per the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html . Any further optimisation would likely be by virtue of astute use of indexes.

Comment: Hmm.. no help from the manual. I managed to create similar query but it didn't help.

I guess problem is that, the table where those log entries are is really big (over 180 million entries). And now it compares that ID to each row and searches the latest and then again and again...

Comment: @GreenBlade Yep, guess I have to try write some kind of script fo that. Would be just perfect to get this working with single query

Comment: @Taapsa try to "explain <query>", build the suitable index; Combine the "where tal1.loggable_id IN (subquery)" and 'inner join companies on companies.id = loggable_id' into 'inner join companies on companies.id = loggable_id and companies.disabled = "3" ' may help;

Comment: Nope, that didn't help much. Query still takes too long, lost connection to database during. @GreenBlade

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select a.id, a.name, a.email, a.content, b.created_at  from
(select companies.id, companies.name, companies.email, tal1.content, tal1.created_at  from
(select companies.id, companies.name, companies.email, tal1.content, tal1.created_at  from log_items tal1) as tal1
left JOIN
(select id, name,email from companies) as companies
on companies.id = tal1.loggable_id
 where tal1.loggable_id IN 
(
"43c24b1d-cd48-4d3b-a75e-2de77a494ab9",
"c43b8c14-4593-4c3c-a383-e609003a09c8",
"5d559355-a4e0-4fea-9f50-fea1bbd8d011",
"f0ce61a2-d8d2-4651-ba12-a79f5515f527"
)) as a
left join
(select tal1.content, tal1.created_at from 
 (select content,created_at from log_items) as   tal1
left JOIN
(select max(created_at) as created_at_max from log_items tal2) as tal2
on  where tal2.loggable_id = tal1.loggable_id) as b

on a.created_at = b.created_at
```

Comment: Hmm.. not working, and I don't want to give those IDs. ID should come from another table.